sending email using emayily, from shiny results in fatal error and an abort, whereas using an R script it works fine
#The following works fine:
library(httr) #http
library(emayili) #email
library(stringr) #string manipulation

smtp_server <- Sys.getenv("SMTP_SERVER")
smtp_port <- Sys.getenv("SMTP_PORT")
smtp_username <- Sys.getenv("SMTP_USERNAME")
IP <- content(GET("https://api.ipify.org?format=json"))$ip

smtp <- server(
  host = smtp_server,
  port = smtp_port,
  username = smtp_username,
  password = Sys.getenv("SMTP_PASSWORD"),
  max_times = 1
)

envelope(
  to = "myemail@yahoo.com",
  from = smtp_username,
  subject = str_c("This is a plain text message!", IP, Sys.time()),
  text = "Hello!"
) |>
smtp()

#The following results in a fatal error though, aborting the r Studio session
library(shiny)
library(httr)
library(emayili)

smtp_server <- Sys.getenv("SMTP_SERVER")
smtp_port <- Sys.getenv("SMTP_PORT")
smtp_username <- Sys.getenv("SMTP_USERNAME")

IP <- content(GET("https://api.ipify.org?format=json"))$ip

smtp <- server(
  host = smtp_server,
  port = smtp_port,
  username = smtp_username,
  password = Sys.getenv("SMTP_PASSWORD"),
  max_times = 1
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("{emayili} & Shiny"),
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML("
      body {
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
      }
      td {
        padding-left: 10px;
      }
    "))
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(
      width = 6,
      tags$table(
        tags$tr(
          tags$th("{emayili version}:"),
          tags$td(as.character(packageVersion("emayili")))
        ),
        tags$tr(
          tags$th("IP address:"),
          tags$td(IP)
        ),
        tags$tr(
          tags$th("SMTP server:"),
          tags$td(smtp_server)
        ),
        tags$tr(
          tags$th("SMTP port:"),
          tags$td(smtp_port)
        )
      )
    ),
    column(
      width = 6,
      class = "text-center",
      actionButton(
        "send",
        "Send Message",
        icon = icon("envelope"),
        class = "btn-primary"
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$send, {
   message("Sending message to ", smtp_username, ".")
    envelope(
      to = smtp_username,
      from = smtp_username,
      subject = strftime(Sys.time(), "{emayili} & Shiny [%F %X]")
    ) %>%
      text("This message was sent from Shiny on {{ IP }} using {emayili}.") %>%
      smtp()
   })
 }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

#Both use the same .Renviron file.
#R 4.4, R Studio 2024.04.2 Build 764
Running the script works ok, but the shiny app crashes.
I tried reinstalling R and reinstalling all libraries.
I have a large app that sends results to the user using emayily. This worked flawlessly until lately, also when deployed on shinyapps.io. Now, it crashes, and I managed to isolate it. Sending the mail from the app, locally on my macbook Apple M3 Pro, 36GB results in the error. The deployed version works fine.

What do the logs say? And I'm confused by your last paragraph - is the app working locally or not?

Thanks for taking a look. The app works when deployed, but crashes locally. The most recent entry in the log file is "2024-07-01T13:35:44.386Z ERROR ERR_FAILED (-2) loading 'file:///Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/Resources/app-arm64/.webpack/renderer/splash/index.html'"
